# How to run aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 in AWS Lambda (Postgres, RDS)

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

According to the AWS docs, you can copy data directly from S3 to a Postgres RDS instance using the following command in PSQL:

```
select aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    'TABLE NAME',
    '',
    '(format csv)',
    'BUCKET NAME',
    'FILE KEY',
    'REGION'
)
```

Ideally I would like to configure a lambda function that is triggered on S3 object create that performs this operation. Is that possible? I know that I could use the psycopg2 library to connect to a Postgres database, but from what I'm read it's unclear if I can use this table import method. I would greatly like to use it because it offers a distinct performance advantage.

Comment: Looks like it would be quick to try this out. Also, the docs I read suggest a different set of parameters to `aws_s3.table_import_from_s3()`, specifically the way the S3 object is indicated as an S3 URI.

Comment: @jarmod you can create an S3 URI but you can also pass information the way I have here which works better with the lambda event info

Comment: Have you figured this out ? Where you able using  the command in a lambda function?

Comment: @RudyVerboven yes, I used the `psycopg2` library and connected with lambda to run it